# Regex: Check for `abc` and then `def` without `123` in between

Tags: regex

How can I use Regex to find every string that starts with `abc`, ends with `def`, but doesn't contain `123` in between?

Comment: Please specify which language or program you are using, regular expression flavors vary greatly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a **Negative Lookahead** here.

```
^abc(?:(?!123).)*def$
```

Regular expression

```
^              # the beginning of the string
abc            # 'abc'
(?:            # group, but do not capture (0 or more times)
 (?!           # look ahead to see if there is not:
  123          # '123'
 )             # end of look-ahead
 .             # any character except \n
)*             # end of grouping
 def           # 'def'
$              # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```